# first date and last date of month from month and year

Tags: sql, oracle

How to get first date and last date of month in oracle by giving input parameter as month.

For eg. if i give input month as 'Jan' and Year as '2016' it should give first date and last date of the month.

Answer (score 2):

You can use TRUNC for that:

First day:

```
TRUNC(your_date, 'MM')
```

Last day:

```
ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(your_date, 'MM'), 1) - 1
```

You basically TRUNC the month to its first day, add one month to get the first day of the next month, and then go back a day.

If you do not have a date in the month but only the month and the year you can simply use the first of each month to construct a date:

```
TO_DATE('1.' || your_month || '.' || your_year, 'DD.MM.YYYY')
ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('1.' || your_month || '.' || your_year, 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 1) - 1
```

Comment: Hi... Here i wont be having date as parameter.... I will get month and year alone .... With that i need to find first day and last day of month

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TRUNC` and `LAST_DAY` functions for this purpose.

```
select TRUNC(d,'MM'), LAST_DAY(d)
from (select to_date('01-2016','MM-YYYY') as d from dual);

01-JAN-2016 00:00:00    31-JAN-2016 00:00:00
```